# generic function in F#

Tags: f#

I'm writing some kind of serialization library (for purpose of learning F#). And now I stuck with this:

Suppose we already have serialization functions for some basic types:

```
type StoreOps =
    static member inline store(x:int) = ...
    static member inline store(x:int64) = ...
    static member inline store(x:float) = ...
    static member inline store(x:float32) = ...
    static member inline store(x:bool) = ...
    static member inline store(x:string) = ...
    ....
```

Now I want to implement generic function to store any array of basic types:

```
let inline store(x:'T[]) = 
        x |> Array.iter StoreOps.store
```

, but compiler can't compile it (error message says: `A unique overload for method 'store' could not be determined based on type information prior to this program point`).

What is a right way to implement such functions in F#? Because I don't want to copy-paste N equal functions for `int[]`, `bool[]`, `float[]`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One workaround is passing `store` functions as a parameter in a generic function:

```
type StoreOps =
    static member inline store (x: int) = ...
    static member inline store (x: int64) = ...
    static member inline store (x: float) = ...
    static member inline store (x: float32) = ...
    static member inline store (x: bool) = ...
    static member inline store (x: string) = ...

    static member storeArray xs f =
        xs |> Array.iter f
    ....

// The compiler chooses the right overload based on types of array elements
StoreOps.storeArray [|100; 200|] StoreOps.store
StoreOps.storeArray [|100L; 200L|] StoreOps.store
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. The only drawback is we have different function name for similar task.

Comment: There is only one `storeArray` function. The duplication is you always pass `StoreOps.store` when you invoke `storeArray` function.

Comment: I mean, we have `StoreOps.store` for `float` and `StoreOps.storeArray` for `float[]`. In ideal world there should be only `StoreOps.store`

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you probably don't need `inline` on the definitions which take arguments of a particular type.  Secondly, the short answer is probably "there's no good way to do that".  However, if you're willing to tolerate horrible hacks, you can do something like:

```
type StoreOps = 
    ... // everything you've currently got

let inline storeArray< ^t, ^u when (^t or ^u) : (static member store : ^u -> unit)> arr = 
    arr 
    |> Array.iter (fun x -> ((^t or ^u) : (static member store : ^u -> unit) x))

type StoreOps with
    static member inline store arr = storeArray<StoreOps,_> arr
```

You can also make the `storeArray` helper private (using `let inline private storeArray...` if you don't want it exposed.

Comment: more a ugly corner of the langage than a hack proper. pretty ugly though ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
type StoreOps = StoreOps with
    static member ($) (StoreOps,x:int)     = (* code for storing *) ()
    static member ($) (StoreOps,x:int64)   = (* code for storing *) ()
    static member ($) (StoreOps,x:float)   = (* code for storing *) ()
    static member ($) (StoreOps,x:float32) = (* code for storing *) ()
    static member ($) (StoreOps,x:bool)    = (* code for storing *) ()
    static member ($) (StoreOps,x:string)  = (* code for storing *) ()

let inline store(x:_[]) = Array.iter (fun a -> StoreOps $ a) x
```

It will generate the constraints for you automatically.